# Adding a custom text to an image and uploading it in javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

So I need to be able to put some text on an image (saved on server so I already have its path) and then save it on the server. I heard that it 's the best to use the canvas, but I can't really find exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: Where is your code and effort?

Comment: Do you mean changing file name or watermark kind of thing?

Comment: I mean something more of a watermark kinf of thing. i 've been thinking about putting a draggable texbox on the image. I managed to do that by using draggable jquery UI, but the problem was, that I still didnt know how to upload the image+textbox back to the server.
EDIT: It also doesn't have to be a textbox, i can make a draggable div, but I still don't know how to upload the div+image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your answer then. Except that your watermark text needs to be a string predefined kind of. And while uploading the image all you have to do is call the specific function used in this official documentation. [Watermark images](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) . All you got to do is instead of image you have to add text. This should help

Comment: Ty very much, i never really realised that this is basically a watermark :D thanx